# Hello Can any one Help me to write this Query in Joins instead of Sub query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT ST.Id,
       ST.Label,
       ST.Asset,
       CASE
           WHEN ST.RFID = '' THEN 'NULL'
           ELSE ST.RFID
       END AS RFID,
       CASE
           WHEN ST.Type = 'O' THEN 'Odometer'
           ELSE 'Engine Hours'
       END AS AccumulatorType,
       ST.AppId,
       ST.Timestamp,
       ST.Accumulator,
       CASE
           WHEN ST.Flag = 0 THEN 'Disabled'
           WHEN ST.Flag = 1 THEN 'Active'
           WHEN ST.Flag = 3 THEN 'Rented'
           WHEN ST.Flag = 4 THEN 'Bypass'
           WHEN ST.Flag = 5 THEN 'Tanker'
       END AS TYPE,

  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM sync
   WHERE RowId = ST.Id
     AND DefinitionId = 1
     AND Status = 1) AS Updated,

  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM sync
   WHERE RowId = ST.Id
     AND DefinitionId = 1
     AND Status = 0) AS Remaining
FROM SecondaryTags AS ST
WHERE AppId = @AppId
```

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far and what errors are you getting? We want to help you learn, but we don't want to just give you the code.

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite the logic?

Comment: Please remove the `C#` Tag, this has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: @JimJimson its fine but i cannot finding a way to create joins by group by same this query , can you guid me how i can convert same Query in Joins and Group By ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff because i m learning and need to convert this query to Joins and Group BY thats main logic

Comment: @BoredomOverload yeah but i have just copied from my C# coding and paste here

Comment: @Nabeel that might be true, nonetheless the question as you've asked it, doesn't require ASP.Net or C# to be tagged.

Comment: @GordonLinoff main issue speed execution too much slow

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you please explain index method so i can speed up too much execution time for this query

Comment: @GordonLinoff you got my issue ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you Solved

Comment: Please google 'stackexchange accept answer' to learn how to click on the check mark symbol to show that an answer helped you & helped you more than any other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to rewrite the logic?  Because you have filtering in the outer query, the subquery is likely to be the most performant method for the calculation.

You can speed the subquery by being sure that you have the write indexes.  In this case, you want an index on `sync(RowId, DefinitionId, StatusId)`:

```
create index idx_sync_rowid_definitionid_statusid
    on sync(RowId, DefinitionId, StatusId)
```

You can rewrite the query as:

```
select . . .,
       s.updated, s.remaining
from SecondaryTags st join
     (select rowid, sum(status = 1) as updated, sum(status = 0) as remaining
      from sync s
      where s.definitionId = 1
      group by s.rowid
     ) s
     on s.rowid = st.id
where st.AppId = @AppId;
```

From a performance perspective, though, I think the index is a better idea.

Comment: Please Detail ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select st.*
     , s.updated
     , s.remaining
  from SecondaryTags st 
  join (select rowid
           , sum(status = 1) as updated
           , sum(status = 0) as remaining
          from sync s
         where s.definitionId = 1
         group 
             by s.rowid
           ) s
 on s.rowid = st.id
where st.AppId = 2;
```